# Android Studio Translation Editor show missing translations (but is not true!)

Tags: android, android-studio, translation, android-studio-3.0, smartgit

Strange effect when updating string resource file with the external tool SmartGIT. Here what I see from the Translation Editor:

[image]

But if I check in the resource file both strings are translated in German (de):

[image]

Rebuilding the project has no effect.

Comment: What exactly is done by SmartGit here?

Comment: I used SmartGit to pull the translation file. Maybe it's not a problem related to SmartGit

Answer (score 6):

This is a recurring issue for me since switching to Android Studio 3.1.

I have branches with different languages supported, and when switching back and forth it seems the cache gets corrupted, and Android Studio fails to scan the other resources directory.

In most cases, **"File --> Invalidate caches / Restart... --> Invalidate and Restart"** seems to fix it.

Comment: Fix it, Google!

Comment: Is this issue filed to Google bug tracker? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: @VadimKotov I have not seen it filed, but didn't really search a lot. Feel free to add a link if you do find it.